# <class 'requests.models.Response'> to Json

Tags: python, json, grequests

I've never done any object oriented programming, only basic script writing.

I'm playing around with grequests

```
rs = (grequests.get('https://api.github.com/repositories?since='+str(page), auth=(login, password)) for page in pages)
blah = grequests.map(rs)
print type(blah[0])
```

The response is:

```
<class 'requests.models.Response'>
```

Normally I convert the response to text and then load it into json so I can parse it, but I can't do that with this response.

I understand the concept of classes but haven't used them or know really what to do with that response.

Is there a way I can convert it to json?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`blah[0]` in your case is a `requests.models.Response` class which, according to the [source code](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L755) and the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/?highlight=json#requests.Response.json), has `json()` method that deserializes the JSON response into a Python object using [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
print blah[0].json()
```

Comment: I tried for response <Response [202]> but got this "JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

Answer (score 6):

Response object can be converted to JSON in two ways.

1. Use the method `.json()` 
   `blah[0].json()`

OR

2. Convert to text and load as json. 
   `json.loads(blah[0].text)`

Comment: I tried for response <Response [202]> but got this "JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

Comment: Check if your file contents are in valid Json format.

Answer (score 0):

today, i'm using only

```
blah.json()
```

And im getting the json value.